# Incorrect operation of the "right" in the carousel Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Pressing the "right" after 3 slides, the page becomes white.
But when you press the "left", ie go to the previous slide all goes well, the slides are changing.
Why are the buttons do not work the same way (to the right) causes a white screen?

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <!--First slide-->
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://picsfab.com/download/image/26763/800x600_dogs-caravan.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;">
                <!--For text to be centered-->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>It's my dogs. Welcome.</h1>
                        <p>This tag will container the text. 
                           This tag will container the text. 
                           This tag will container the text.
                        </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Sign up</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Second slide-->
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://picsfab.com/download/image/82752/800x600_yukon-dogs-cold-for-cats-canada-expedition.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;">
                <!--For text to be centered-->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>It's my dogs. Welcome.</h1>
                        <p>This tag will container the text. 
                           This tag will container the text. 
                           This tag will container the text.
                        </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Sign up</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <!--Third slide-->
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://picsfab.com/download/image/81152/800x600_sobaka-drug-wizard-dog.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;">
                <!--For text to be centered-->
                <div class="container">
                   <div class="carousel-caption">
                       <h1>It's my dogs. Welcome.</h1>
                       <p>This tag will container the text. 
                          This tag will container the text. 
                          This tag will container the text.
                       </p>
                       <p><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Sign up</a></p>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>       

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div> <!--  Carousel inner-->
    </div> <!--  Carousel-->
</div>  <!--  Container-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All works!

```
        </div> <!--  Carousel inner-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
```